# How to increase item in a tuple

Tags: python, loops, tuples

6 and im trying to create sort of a loop to increase the item in a tuple example;

```
list = [1,2,3]  
print (list[0]*<----this is where im trying to create a loop*)
```

(so the output shows this)

```
    out:  1
```

basically separate the integers and use them individually in a loop
this is what i got so far

```
list = [1, 2, 3]  
list2 = [11, 12, 13]  
i = (0)  
i = i+1  
print ("tuples", list[0+i], list2[0+i])
```

but i got this as a result

```
out: 2, 12
```

and im trying to get this as a result

```
out: 1, 11  
out: 2, 12  
out: 3, 13
```

Comment: You're using the term "tuple" to refer to lists.  In Python, a tuple is different from a list.  Also, there are no loops in the code you posted.

Comment: I was just using list as a place holder, I am using a tuple because is immutable to an extend, didn't want to disclose the actual code(complex and silly variables), sorry for the confusion , thank you tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]  
list2 = [11, 12, 13] 

list3=[(list1[i],list2[i]) for i in range(len(list1))]
#[(1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13)]
```

This is a list comprehension.

It's expanded for would be

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    print( list1[i],list2[i] )

1 11
2 12
3 13
```

Comment: ref for OP -- `[(list1[i],list2[i]) for i in range(len(list1))]` is an operation called list comprehension. see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: thank you that helped a lot sorting the lists ,but i'm trying to create a loop where list1[0+i(increase this number)] and print the increasing value until it reaches the maximum which will be three, but so far it only prints the second value, how can i loop it so it does that three times thank you for the link too

Comment: @papisilv I did not get you, can you add what your expected output would be in a clear format? Is it `[ (1,2,3), (11,12,13) ]` ?

Comment: sure im trying to get this ///output : [1,11] //// output [2,12] /////output[3,13] instead of doing this print(list1[0])  and print(list1[1]) and print(list1[2]), it might not be possible or too complex for my basic understanding sorry

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid creating a variable called `list` as that is a native Python keyword already!

You can also consider using `zip` in a loop if you want to operate both lists at the same time like this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]  
list2 = [11, 12, 13] 

for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    print x, y
```

Output:

```
1 11
2 12
3 13
```

Comment: yeah i just used list as a place holder for the name, i did not feel  like disclosing the  silly labels i use, thank you tho